# adonis in vegan: limiting permutations when design isn't fully blocked

Tags: r, permutation-test, blocking, vegan

I have read over the help files and examples online on using adonis with blocked designs but haven't really found a solution to my particular case. I'm fairly new to permutation-based methods so apologies if my question doesn't make much sense.

I have an experimental design that is constituted of a factor with three levels (let's call them A,B and C), one of which (C) is the "control". I am mainly interested in testing the hypotheses that any of the 2 "treatments" differs from the control (if it helps clarify, it is a test of mimicry, A&B are parts of an insect's body and C is the flower where it's found, such that if any AB contrasts with C I can reject it, but I'm not really interested in differences between A&B). I am defining my contrasts accordingly, but when it comes to defining the null hypothesis and therefore how to permute samples to create the null distribution in adonis, I'm a bit stuck, because I feel that permutations should be conducted only within groups but including the control. That is, samples from A should be shuffled between A&C and samples from B between B&C, but not between A&B. If this were a fully blocked design and C was actually divided in 2 blocks, one for each A&B, then I think I would know how to define it, but I'm not really sure in this case.

```
dat <- c(rnorm(50,0,1), rnorm(50,1,1), rnorm(50,1,1))
grp <- factor(rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=50))

contrasts(grp) <- cbind(c(0.5, 0.5, -1),
                    c(0,0,0))

dds <- dist(dat)


adonis(dds~grp) #without any blocking
```

Does this make any sense? Should I be accounting for these relationships when defining how to permute samples for the null, or is it the case that by transitivity it doesn't really matter if I permute between my "treatments"?